# Setting int variable causing error

Tags: ios, debugging, variables, runtime-error, objective-c++

I have posted about this in the past but now this is really confusing me. I have a variable named _state. It is suppose to keep track of GameCenter state. When I do...

```
int BBGameCenter::GameCenterState(){
    return _state;
}
```

return _state; is throwing an exc_bad_access. I originally thought this was because _state was null so I have been debugging in that manner. However, when I tried...

```
int BBGameCenter::GameCenterState(){
    _state = 0;
    return _state;
}
```

I received the same error message but this time it was on the line I was setting the variable and not the return statement at all. So I am now throughly confused. What about setting a variable for an int causes the runtime-error exc_bad_access? The full GameCenter code is below. Thanks for your help!

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
@interface BBGameCenterDelegate : NSObject{
}
@end
class BBGameCenter{

    static BBGameCenter *_gameCenter;

    int _state;

    BBGameCenterDelegate *_delegate;

    NSMutableArray *_achievements;

public:
    BBGameCenter();

    static BBGameCenter *GetGameCenter();

    bool GameCenterAvail();

    void StartGameCenter();
    int  GameCenterState();

    void ShowLeaderboard( String leaderboard_ID );
    void ReportScore( int score,String leaderboard_ID );

    void ShowAchievements();
    void ReportAchievement( float percent,String achievement_ID );
    float GetAchievementPercent( String id );

    /
    GKAchievement *FindAchievement( String id );

    void GameCenterViewControllerDidFinish( UIViewController *vc );
};
/
BBGameCenter *BBGameCenter::_gameCenter;
@implementation BBGameCenterDelegate
-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*)vc{
    BBGameCenter::GetGameCenter()->GameCenterViewControllerDidFinish( vc );
}
-(void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController*)vc{
    BBGameCenter::GetGameCenter()->GameCenterViewControllerDidFinish( vc );
}
- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)vc{
    BBGameCenter::GetGameCenter()->GameCenterViewControllerDidFinish( vc );
}
@end
BBGameCenter::BBGameCenter():_state(-1),_delegate(0),_achievements(0){
    if( !GameCenterAvail() ) return;
    _delegate=[[BBGameCenterDelegate alloc] init];
    _state=0;
}
BBGameCenter *BBGameCenter::GetGameCenter(){
    if( !_gameCenter ) _gameCenter=new BBGameCenter();
    return _gameCenter;
}
bool BBGameCenter::GameCenterAvail(){

    /
    Class gcClass=NSClassFromString( @"GKLocalPlayer" );

    /
    NSString *reqSysVer=@"4.1";
    NSString *currSysVer=[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL osVersionSupported=([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch]!=NSOrderedAscending);

    return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}
void BBGameCenter::StartGameCenter(){

    if( _state ) return;

    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer=[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    if( localPlayer ){
        _state=1;
        [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
            if( localPlayer.isAuthenticated ){
                [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements,NSError *error){
                    if( achievements ){
                        _achievements=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        [_achievements addObjectsFromArray:achievements];
                        /
                         int n=[_achievements count];
                         for( int i=0;i<n;++i ){
                         GKAchievement *achievement=[_achievements objectAtIndex:i];
                         bbPrint( String("Achievement:")+String(achievement.identifier) );
                         }
                         */
                    }
                    _state=2;
                }];
            }else{
                _state=-1;
            }
        }];
    }else{
        _state=-1;
    }
}
```

Error Occurs here vvv

```
int BBGameCenter::GameCenterState(){
    return _state;
    }
void BBGameCenter::ShowLeaderboard( String leaderboard_ID ){

    if( _state!=2 ) return;

    GKLeaderboardViewController *vc=[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if( !vc ) return;

    vc.leaderboardDelegate=(id)_delegate;
    vc.timeScope=GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
    vc.category=leaderboard_ID.ToNSString();

    _state=3;

    /
    /
    [BBIosGame::IosGame()->GetUIAppDelegate()->viewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
void BBGameCenter::ReportScore( int value,String leaderboard_ID ){

    if( _state!=2 ) return;

    GKScore *score=[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:leaderboard_ID.ToNSString()];

    score.value=value;
    score.context=0;

    [score reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){} ];
}
void BBGameCenter::ShowAchievements(){

    if( _state!=2 ) return;

    GKAchievementViewController *vc=[[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if( !vc ) return;

    vc.achievementDelegate=(id)_delegate;

    _state=4;

    /
    /
    [BBIosGame::IosGame()->GetUIAppDelegate()->viewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
GKAchievement *BBGameCenter::FindAchievement( String id ){
    if( !_achievements ) return 0;
    NSString *str=id.ToNSString();
    int n=[_achievements count];
    for( int i=0;i<n;++i ){
        GKAchievement *achievement=[_achievements objectAtIndex:i];
        if( [achievement.identifier isEqualToString:str] ) return achievement;
    }
    return 0;
}
void BBGameCenter::ReportAchievement( float percent,String achievement_ID ){

    if( _state!=2 ) return;

    GKAchievement *achievement=FindAchievement( achievement_ID );
    if( !achievement ){
        achievement=[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:achievement_ID.ToNSString()];
        [_achievements addObject:achievement];
    }

    achievement.percentComplete=percent;
    achievement.showsCompletionBanner=true;

    [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){} ];
}
float BBGameCenter::GetAchievementPercent( String achievement_ID ){

    GKAchievement *achievement=FindAchievement( achievement_ID );
    if( !achievement ) return 0;

    return achievement.percentComplete;
}
void BBGameCenter::GameCenterViewControllerDidFinish( UIViewController *vc ){

    _state=2;

   /
    /
    [BBIosGame::IosGame()->GetUIAppDelegate()->viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: woah, this is a messy mix of languages - I cannot tell where classes and methods start and/or end. Have you thought about sticking to one language per file?

Comment: Just a hunch, but check the value of self, I suspect that you haven't allocated your class instance.

Comment: Start by splitting the C++ and Objective-C++ and then post the stacktrace.  It's not even clear why you are creating a C++ class at all; just use Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing the header file but think I see the problem. I'm assuming you're defining an Objective C property and trying to access it from a C++ class.

From here on, it's all guesswork and you should really just drop the C++ or at least split it. The C++ sees the line

```
@property int _state
```

...and thinks it's alright as it sees a global variable. but when you compile the program, it is inside a class and you haven't initialized it or accessed it by doing something like

```
bbgcDelegate.state
```

So when the C++ code tries to access the variable, there's nothing there, hence the error. In essence, somehow you've tricked the IDE into accepting this code but it shouldn't have compiled.

Comment: This was in fact the issue. Thank you so much for your help! :)